# What's better? Call function in foreach or call foreach in function?

Tags: php, laravel, function, generics, foreach

I'm trying to improve my code and now I'm wondering what's better (performance & code style):

```php
public function xxx() {
    ...
    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        $this->createCustomer($customer);
    }
    ...
}

public function createCustomer($customer) {
    // Create customer
}
```

or

```php
public function xxx() {
    ...
    $this->createCustomers($customers);
    ...
}

public function createCustomers($customers) {
    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        // Create customer
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: no noticable difference between both solutions. you still do create the customers one by one. Better insert all customers in the same time.

Comment: You are doing the same thing just starting from different places. There will be no difference in executing it.

Answer (score 1):

Here a better version

```
public function xxx() {
    ...
    $ToBeCreatedCustomers = validateAndFormatCustomers($customers)
    Customer::insert($ToBeCreatedCustomers);
    ...
}

public function validateAndFormatCustomers() {
    $ToBeCreatedCustomers = []
    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        $ToBeCreatedCustomers[] = [
            'name' => $customer['name'],
            .....
        ]
    }
    return $ToBeCreatedCustomers;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the SPR, the first option is more correct. But the second option will be more productive.

Comment: Can you please explain SPR or what it stands for?